# How to use \foreach and \newtheorem together?

Tags: arrays, foreach, expandafter, listofitems, latexpand

I want to use `\foreach` and `newtheorem` together, so I've assigned an array with the package `listofitems`

```tex
\setsepchar{;/,}\ignoreemptyitems

\readlist\baz
{
theorem,     lemma,     definition, corollary,
proposition, postulate, axiom,      remark;
}
```

And I typed `\newtheorem{\baz[1,3]}{\baz[1,3]}[chapter]` there will create a `definition` environment, so I want to create a series of `amsthm` environments with a `foreach` loop

```tex
\foreach \a in {1,2,...,8}
{
    \newtheorem{\baz[1,\a]}{\baz[1,\a]}
}
```

However, it returned errors `\begin{document} ended by \end{definition}`, may means that the `amsthm` environments were not successfully defined at all.

So how can I fix this?

The complete MWE is the following

```tex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{geometry,amsthm,listofitems,pgffor}

\setsepchar{;/,}\ignoreemptyitems

\readlist*\baz
    {
        theorem, lemma, definition, corollary, proposition, postulate, axiom, remark;
    }

\foreach \x in {1,8}
{
    \newtheorem{\baz[1,\x]}{\baz[1,\x]}
}

\newtheorem{\baz[1,3]}{\baz[1,3]}[chapter]


\begin{document}

\begin{definition}
    
\end{definition}

% \begin{theorem}
    
% \end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this using `listofitems` forms, without resorting to L3 syntax.  As mentioned by others, `\foreach` loops (or, for `listofitems`, `foreachitem` loops) are in their own group.  The solution is to globally add the desired [expanded] tokens to a token list (`\mytoks`) and execute the token list after exiting the `\foreachitem` loop.

In the case of `listofitems` arrays, two expansions are required to recover the desired tokens.

Also, I added a semicolon separator to the middle of your list just to show that this approach can work across sublists.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{geometry,amsthm,listofitems,pgffor}
\newtoks\mytoks
\newcommand\addtomytoks[1]{\global\mytoks\expandafter{\the\mytoks#1}}
\newcommand\xaddtomytoks[1]{\expandafter\addtomytoks\expandafter{#1}}
\newcommand\xxaddtomytoks[1]{\expandafter\xaddtomytoks\expandafter{#1}}
\newcommand\xxaddgrouptomytoks[1]{\xxaddtomytoks{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{#1}}}
\setsepchar{;/,}\ignoreemptyitems

\readlist*\baz
    {
        theorem, lemma, definition, corollary; proposition, postulate, axiom, remark;
    }

\mytoks{}
\foreachitem\z\in\baz[]{%
\foreachitem\x\in\baz[\zcnt]{%
    \addtomytoks{\newtheorem}%
    \xxaddgrouptomytoks{\baz[\zcnt,\xcnt]}%
    \xxaddgrouptomytoks{\baz[\zcnt,\xcnt]}%
}}
\the\mytoks


\begin{document}

\begin{definition}
    
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}
    
\end{theorem}

\begin{postulate}
    
\end{postulate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

It's the usual problem: every item in a `\foreach` cycle is performed inside a group, so the environments defined through `\newtheorem` are forgotten as soon as the group ends.

I guess that the idea is to batch define

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
...
```

I don't think you gain much from this, but out of academic interest here's how you can do it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\definetheorems}{mom}
 {% #1 = base, #2 = optional parent counter, #3 = list of other names
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}
   {
    \exp_args:Nne \newtheorem{#1}{\text_titlecase:n { #1 }}
   }
   {
    \exp_args:Nne \newtheorem{#1}{\text_titlecase:n { #1 }}[#2]
   }
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #3 }
   {
    \axia_newtheorem:nne { #1 } { ##1 } { \text_titlecase:n { ##1 } }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \axia_newtheorem:nnn
 {
  \newtheorem{#2}[#1]{#3}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \axia_newtheorem:nnn { nne }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\definetheorems{theorem}[section]{
  lemma, definition, corollary, proposition, postulate, axiom, remark
}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\begin{lemma}
This is a lemma.
\end{lemma}

\begin{axiom}
This is an axiom.
\end{axiom}

\begin{theorem}
This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

\section{Again}

\begin{proposition}
This is a proposition.
\end{proposition}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is the output if the call is without the optional argument `[section]`:

[image]

#### Comment

You lose a lot with this approach, for instance the possibility of applying different theorem styles and you're also bound to just slight changes in the theorem labels (here capitalizing the first letter).

Comment: Thank you very much! For the styles you mentioned, actually, I used the `listofitems` package to read a 2-d array, such as `\readlist*\baz{lemma,axiom;green,blue}`, the first line is the name of the `amsthm` environment and the second line is the color of the title. Then, I used the `foreach` loop to create every environment and color the title of them, just like `\newtheorem{\baz[1,\x]}{\color{\baz[2,\x]}\baz[1,\x]}` (Although I know this is hard in LaTeX2e with foreach).